# API gateway body mapper nested objects

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have an endpoint setup on API gateway that is talking directly to DynamoDB.

As a post request comes in I use the body mapper script to map my url request parameters to dynamoDB params.

#### My URL params

```
{
  "name": "sdaf",
  "location": "asdf",
  "gender": "male"
}
```

#### Body Mapper Script

```
{ 
  "TableName": "sample-table",
  "Item": {
    "firstName": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.name')"
    },
    "location": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.location')"
    }
  }
}
```

All of this works fine until I have to write a whole object to dynamo.

#### New URL Params

```
{
  "name": "sdaf",
  "location": "asdf",
  "gender": "male",
  "hobbies": {
    "hobby1": {
      "startedAt": "<some time>" 
    },
    "hobby2": {
      "startedAt": "<some time>" 
    },
  }
}
```

I am not sure how the body mapper is supposed to look like for this situation?
I have tried this:

#### Body Mapper

```
{ 
  "TableName": "sample-table",
  "Item": {
    "firstName": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.name')"
    },
    "location": {
        "S": "$input.path('$.location')"
    },
    "hobbies": {
        "M": "$input.path('$.hobbies')"
    }
  }
}
```

But doesn't work. I wonder if there is a way to dump an object into a column in dynamo from the api gateway directly. I know this is possible with adding a lambda in between but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be made to work while passing hobbies as a URL parameter.

If you instead pass hobbies in the body, you can do something like this:

```
"M": {
#foreach( $elem in $input.path('$.hobbies'))
      $elem
  #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
      }
```